# linear algebra eigenvalue proof question

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that a 2 × 2 matrix with just one eigenvalue (of multiplicity two) is diagonalizable if and only if it is already a diagonal matrix.

So, by multiplicity two, I'm guessing it just means you have two of the same eigenvalues, but I'm confused at how to approach and do this problem.

Comment: Multiplicity in this case is referring to [algebraic multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if it is diagonalizable, what would the corresponding diagonal matrix look like?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1190292)

Comment: @DMcMor What do you have against hints?